# JS - How to change the way arrow keys move the cursor in text

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create an editor with CSS "writing-mode: vertical-rl".

```html
<div 
    id="textEditArea" 
    style="
        writing-mode: vertical-rl; 
        font-size: 24px; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%;
        outline: none;
    "
    contenteditable
>
    Input here
</div>
```

It looks perfect at the beginning.
However, I found it weird after pressing the arrow keys - I expected when pressing up/down, it moves the cursor up/down in the same vertical row, but it moved the cursor right/left in different lines. It works the same bad when pressing left/right. (BTW I use Chrome 85 in Linux)(It works perfectly on Firefox 82 in Linux)

I tried faking a KeyboardEvent of up/down/right/left when pressing right/left/down/up. But it just didn't move. (I'm not pretty sure if it was my problem that I used it incorrectly. I didn't save the code.)

I tried using document.getSelection(), but it didn't work perfectly if a row is too long that the browser auto-breaks it. It also skipped empty rows.

```js
     
        function getPreviousTextNode(org){
            var newNode = org;
            while(newNode == org /*|| newNode.nodeName != "#text"*/ || newNode.nodeName == "BR"){
                if(newNode.childNodes.length != 0){
                    newNode = newNode.lastChild;
                }else if(newNode.previousSibling != null){
                    newNode = newNode.previousSibling;
                }else if(newNode.parentNode.previousSibling != document.querySelector("#textEditArea")){
                    newNode = newNode.parentNode.previousSibling;
                }else{
                    newNode = org;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return newNode;
        }
         
        function getNextTextNode(org){
            var newNode = org;
            while(newNode == org /*|| newNode.nodeName != "#text"*/ || newNode.nodeName == "BR"){
                if(newNode.childNodes.length != 0){
                    newNode = newNode.firstChild;
                }else if(newNode.nextSibling != null){
                    newNode = newNode.nextSibling;
                }else if(newNode.parentNode.nextSibling != document.querySelector("#textEditArea")){
                    newNode = newNode.parentNode.nextSibling;
                }else{
                    newNode = org;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return newNode;
        }
         
         window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
            switch(event.key){
                case "ArrowLeft": 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var newNode = getNextTextNode(document.getSelection().focusNode);
                    var curOffset = document.getSelection().focusOffset;
                    document.getSelection().collapse(newNode, (newNode.length > curOffset)? curOffset: newNode.length);
                    console.log("left");
                    break;
                    
                case "ArrowRight":
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var newNode = getPreviousTextNode(document.getSelection().focusNode);
                    var curOffset = document.getSelection().focusOffset;
                    document.getSelection().collapse(newNode, (newNode.length > curOffset)? curOffset: newNode.length);
                    console.log("right");
                    break;
                    
                case "ArrowUp":
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if(document.getSelection().focusOffset != 0){
                        document.getSelection().collapse(document.getSelection().focusNode, document.getSelection().focusOffset -1);
                    }else{
                        newNode = getPreviousTextNode(document.getSelection().focusNode);
                        document.getSelection().collapse(newNode, newNode.length);
                    }
                    console.log("up");
                    break;
                    
                case "ArrowDown":
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if(document.getSelection().focusOffset != document.getSelection().focusNode.length){
                        document.getSelection().collapse(document.getSelection().focusNode, document.getSelection().focusOffset +1);
                    }else{
                        document.getSelection().collapse(getNextTextNode(document.getSelection().focusNode), 0);
                    }
                    console.log("down");
                    break;
            }
                    
        });
```

```html
<div 
    id="textEditArea" 
    style="
        writing-mode: vertical-rl; 
        font-size: 24px; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%;
        outline: none;
    "
    contenteditable
>
    Input here. This is with the code to solve the problem caused by "writing-mode: vertical-rl". However, it failed.
</div>
```

So, what I'm looking for is a way to **change how arrow keys move the cursor**, or a way to **exchange the actions of up/down/right/left and right/left/down/up**.

(Sorry for my poor English and terrible coding skill.)

Answer (score 0):

whats up !

i saw this at mdn

> 1] Internet Explorer, Edge (16 and earlier), and Firefox (36 and
> earlier) use "Left", "Right", "Up", and "Down" instead of "ArrowLeft",
> "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp", and "ArrowDown".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#Navigation_keys

diffrent browsers use diffrent word for the event

this is why you should use the key code for every button on your keyboard instead

https://keycode.info/

this website will give you the code

see how i used it to manipulate the colors in my paint project

the link to the code

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/paint-painties?path=index.html%3A62%3A14

the link to the website

https://paint-painties.glitch.me/

maybe try instead of using the switch case "ArrowUp" to code

```
# arrow left  key code is 37 # 
## arrow up key code is 38 ##
### arrow right key code is 39 ###
#### arrow down key code is 40 ####
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I mean the problem occurs on Google Chrome. Without any js (like the first one), it works as perfectly as I thought it should. However, thanks for your advice ️.

Comment: now i understand your problem better , you tried to write vertically and the problem was with pressing the arrowkeys to move between to letters ... so did you was able to fix your bug  ??? also   ,am i know it sounds terrible but can u mark my answer as good ? :) im trying to get some points and answering you took me a lot of time :)

Comment: Well... I haven't solved the problem yet - Actually I gave up, cuz it took me so much time. I'll vote-up your answer. Nothing is better than helping others ️. BTW if you cannot see any change may because of the response I got - "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I don't really understand how this forum works ️.